# Nodejs version and NPM out of sync

Tags: node.js, npm

I have nodejs installed on a windows machine.
Node -v = v12.13.0
was following a tutorial and author had me switch to npm version 5.5.1

Now, most npm commands fail because it seems to be incompatible with this version of nodejs.

So, I cannot use npm to change the version of node.  seems like a catch 22.

I uninstalled Nodejs and reinstalled, but it kept me at version 5.5.1 of npm.

I'm wondering if there is a manual way to upgrade npm back to the current version.

Comment: Id suggests removing your instillation of Node, use [nvm](https://github.com/coreybutler/nvm-windows) to manage switching between Node versions.

Comment: Have you tried running `npm i npm@latest -g`?

Comment: npm and nodejs are separate programs with separate version numbers.  They are not supposed to be the same version number.  That said, some installations of node.js via installers will also install the latest/matching version of npm.

Comment: Yes, I understand the version numbers are not supposed to be the same.  npm latest will not work.  As mentioned, all NPM commands fail because npm 5.5.1 does not work with node v12.13.0.  I did finally get this fixed by issuing a curl command to get the latest npm version.  thanks.